# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]' for Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store my database value into a class, but i was unable to convert it into my class using DataSnapshot. I have already added all necessary null safety operators. But it still shows an error.

```
class User {
  String userID = "";
  String name = "";
  String phoneNo = "";
  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  User(
      {required this.userID,
      required this.name,
      required this.phoneNo,
      required this.email,
      required this.password});

  User.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    userID = dataSnapshot.key!;
    if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
      name = dataSnapshot.value!["name"] as String;
      email = dataSnapshot.value!['email'];
      phoneNo = dataSnapshot.value!['phone'];
      password = dataSnapshot.value!['password'];
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to define the snapshot value as a String but also the same as others.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHN90.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
      final data = dataSnapshot.value as Map;
      name = data["name"] as String;
      email = data['email'] as String;
      phoneNo = data['phone'] as String;
      password = data['password'] as String;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the type of your DataSnapshot:

```
  User.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> dataSnapshot) {
        userID = dataSnapshot.key!;
        if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
          name = dataSnapshot.value!["name"] as String;
          email = dataSnapshot.value!['email'];
          phoneNo = dataSnapshot.value!['phone'];
          password = dataSnapshot.value!['password'];
        }
      }
```